# How would I separate an double into 3 smaller doubles in Java and set those new doubles as variables?

Tags: java

Say I have a a 15-digit double:

> 123451234512345

How would I split that into three 5-digit doubles? Like this:

> 12345 12345 12345

and set each of those new doubles to a new variable?

> a = 12345, b = 12345, c = 12345

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you actually getting the value as an integer?  Because your example value would overflow.

Comment: actualy, now that I think about it, it would need to be a double anyway because of what I plan to do with it. Does this help? I'll edit my post. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: If it really is a whole number that is 15 digits or less, you could use `long`.  If you need really large numbers you will need to use strings or something like `BigInteger`.

Comment: Do you know `double`s are not integer values? `long` might be more suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `long` representation, you can use the modulo operator `%` and the integer division `/` as follows:

```
long myInput = 123451234512345;
long a = myInput % 100000;
long b = (myInput / 100000) % 100000;
long c = (myInput / (100000 * 100000)) % 100000;
```

In a more general way that *could* be used in a loop:

```
long myInput = 123451234512345;
long a = myInput % 100000;
myInput /= 100000;
long b = myInput % 100000;
myInput /= 100000;
long c = myInput % 100000;
```

Note: this second version modifies the variable `myInput`.

Comment: I ended up using your second solution and it works exactly as I wanted. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 2):

In a loop, take the original number and get the remainder when dividing by 100,000 (`% 100000`) to take the next 5-digit number.  Divide the original by 100,000 (`/ 100000`).  If it's non-zero, then continue the loop, else you've extracted all 5-digit numbers.

If you are dealing with 15-digit numbers, then use a `long` to store the number, as it's much too big to fit in an `int`.

Comment: would that work for a double? sorry for the confusion and thanks for your help.

Comment: For `double`s, the precision should be less than or equal to `1`.  It will work for values up to 2^52.  Any higher, and the precision of a `double` is greater than `1` and you may be storing a different value than you specify.  So you might as well use `long`, which can go to 2^63 - 1.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to string divide it in three parts and convert string to double.

```
String text = 123451234512345+"";
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
int index = 0;
while (index<text.length()) {
    strings.add(text.substring(index, Math.min(index+5,text.length()));
    index+=5;
}
double a = Double.parseDouble(strings[0]);
double b = Double.parseDouble(strings[1]);
double c = Double.parseDouble(strings[2]);
```

Comment: IMHO, using Strings for this purpose is much work for a very simple numeric operation that computers handle much more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. First convert the number into String. Then place a space after every 5 digits. Then split against the space.

```
String str = "123451234512345";
String []splits = str.replaceAll("(\\d{5})", "$1 ").split(" "); 
for(String s: splits){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Another option, and better one, using pattern matcher.

```
String str = "123451234512345";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{5})");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Feel free to transfer the values from the array to integer variable.

Comment: IMHO, using Strings for this purpose is much work for a very simple numeric operation that computers handle much more easily.

Comment: @Joffrey yes, you are right. But can be written in a quick time.

Comment: Well, I really believe my answer is much easier to come up with ^^ It would take me much more time to find the suitable regular expression that you used, but that's very subjective, I agree. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: @Joffrey what about the biginteger has 30 `12345` in total :-)

Comment: A simple loop would do, and it will still be simpler I think ;)

Comment: That case looping will be slower than regex matching as its a big number!